Каково назначение аргумента sender в Событиях?
Недавно приступил к изучению темы Событий в C#, последняя тема перед оконными приложениями. При объяснении конвенции оформления событий преподаватель множество раз уточнял, что причина существования и самой конвенции, и отдельных решений внутри нее (в частности, того же sender-а) в том, что во времена ее создания в C# еще не было ни LINQ, ни лямбда-выражений, и сейчас с их помощью те же самые задачи можно решать намного эффективнее (ссылка на первоисточник).
В связи с тем, что курс по которому я учусь достаточно старый (создан около 10 лет) у меня вопрос: повлияло ли появление LINQ и лямбда-выражений на правила оформления Событий в C#, и существует ли до сих пор сама конвенция их оформления, или можно использовать LINQ и делегаты на полную?) Заранее спасибо!

Нашел у Майкрософт следующую информацию. Согласно данным соглашениям, использование лямбда-выражений прямо рекомендовано для определения обработчиков событий. Не знаю я, кому верить...

Не совсем понимаю, при чём здесь Linq и лямбды. Приведите какой-нибудь код в примерах, чтобы было что обсуждать. В обработчиках событий sender нужен, чтобы можно было не завязываться на конкретный элемент интерфейса. Например, вы можете повесить один обработчик событий на 10 разных кнопок, и перекрашивать конкретную кнопку по нажатию на неё опираясь именно на sender - он ссылается на тот элемент интерфейса, к которому относится случившееся событие. А не писать в обработчике перекраску конкретной кнопки интерфейса Button1. Это обеспечивает гибкость разработки.

Спасибо за ответ! Т.к. я только изучаю вопрос, то могу сослаться только на пример, приведенный в уроке. Если переписать его тут, то получится полторы страницы одного только кода. Возможно, будет лучше дать ссылку на оригинальный урок, он короткий: https://youtu.be/cCmBRwPG2lo?si=zK4DzVeJoAZfYOb3

"ссылка на первоисточник" - это ржака, но работает, что удивительно.

А, ну глянул я видео. Ну, можно и так, конечно. Но лучше пусть события будут событиями. Я бы продолжал передавать sender в обработчик, даже если он там сейчас не нужен. Сейчас не нужен, а вдруг надо будет что-то. Конвенция есть конвенция. Кроме того, тут получается всё перемешано в одном коде и наполнение контролов и обработка, и шаблонизаторы не используются. В общем, вы лучше разберитесь, как оба варианта использовать, а потом в конкретных проектах уже поймёте, как вам лучше. Скорее всего у вас будет какой-то ещё более продвинутый фреймворк, там такого ручного труда всё-равно не будет.

@CrazyElf если я правильно понял, то между показанными вариантами с точки зрения их функциональности разницы нет - просто в примере с лямбдами и LINQ мы передаем ссылку непосредственно на метод-обработчик, а не на метод-посредник, единственная роль которого соблюсти сигнатуру EventHandler. Соответственно код короче и удобнее. Нет того, что можно сделать со вторым вариантом кода и нельзя сделать с первым. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь, ибо у меня пока в голове все как следует не улеглось.
Меня больше интересуют скорее требования кодстайла к оформлению событий, от этого зависит то, что я буду учить.

Если у вас простой элемент интерфейса, от которого вам нужно одно статическое свойство, которое никак не меняется, то, конечно, с лямбдой проще будет. Но так будет не со всеми элементами и не всегда.

А можно попросить, если не трудно, пару примеров (просто на словах) в какой ситуации лямбды будут не пригодны, и придется делать "по старинке"? Хотелось бы все таки понимать разницу в возможностях, если она есть.

@rotabor а что не так с первоисточником?)

Смотрите.
Для начала, стандартные события — это штука, определённая не на уровне C# и не на уровне прости господи WinForms. Гайдлайны по созданию событий придуманы в самом .NET, и они должны работать во всех языках, которые поддерживаются .NET: и в C#, и в Visual Basic, и в экзотике наподобие IronPython (вот полный список).
Фреймворк .NET не привязан к C# и не имеет права исходить из того, что в вашем языке найдутся удобные замыкания. Впрочем, в C# на момент принятия этой конвенции тоже не было замыканий.
(А вот LINQ к такому определению событий не при чём, конечно: всё то же было бы и без LINQ.)

А вот в вашем собственном коде вы можете определять события как вы хотите, например так:
public event Action EverythingCrashed;

Но будьте готовы к тому, что у ваших коллег, которые привыкли к определениям по гайдлайнам, поднимутся брови, и вам придётся отстаивать ваше решение.

Нужна ли эта старая конвенция всё ещё в C#, или к ней следует относиться как к архаике? Иногда нужна.
Когда вы пишете код UI, вы можете позволить себе неэкономное расходование ресурсов, потому что этот код выполняется нечасто.
Но если ваш код более низкого уровня, то с использованием лямбд есть особенность: каждая лямбда, которая захватывает переменные, — это новый объект, который размещается в куче и немного нагружает сборщик мусора. Для кода, который выполняется очень часто или очень много раз, это может стать реальной проблемой, и много раз по «немного» превращается во «много». В этом случае вы захотите по старинке завести один общий метод, который будет подписан на событие, а свой контекст (то есть, дополнительную информацию, наподобие названия месяца в примере) получить из sender и args.
Кстати, лямбда вовсе не обязательно размещается в куче. Если лямбда не захватывает никакие переменные, то компилятор достаточно умён, чтобы превратить её в метод. Для того, чтобы убедиться, что ваша лямбда ничего не захватывает, даже придумали специальный модификатор static (static x => x * x). Но такие лямбды, конечно, не могут захватывать состояние, и вам придётся «доставлять» контекст в метод снова-таки при помощи sender/args.

Как же нужно правильно определять события? «Правильного» пути нет, каждый программист (если вы работаете в команде — каждая команда) определяет для себя самостоятельно.
Вы можете следовать гайдлайнам .NET, тогда ваш код будет более привычным. Вы можете проигнорировать гайдлайны и определять события, поставляя в обработчик лишь ту информацию, которая абсолютна необходима, в этом случае код, использующий события, будет более удобным. Решать лишь вам (вашей команде).
Если вы пишете библиотеку общего пользования, то имеет смысл следовать гайдлайнам, чтобы не создавать сюрпризов для ваших пользователей. Если вы пишете код, являющийся частью большего фреймворка (например, View-часть в WPF- или WinForms-приложении), имеет смысл тоже определять события так же, как и в остальном коде (то есть согласно гайдлайнам). А если вы пишете код нижних уровней, тут можно и применить нестандартный подход, если он вам больше по душе.

Благодарю, теперь ясно почему все так. По поводу нагрузки на сборщик мусора я знал, но хорошо что вы напомнили, хороший аргумент в пользу стандартного оформления событий. Могу я попросить, если не затруднит - дайте ссылку на источник, где можно увидеть правильное оформление событий, или напишите в ответе.

@James Bond: Дополнил ответ

Кстати, той же цели, что и sender, служит параметр AsyncState в древнем IAsyncResult/BeginInvoke.

Благодарю! P.S. Еще вспомнил что на лекции что-то говорилось про то, что поскольку лямбда с зымыканием разворачивается в анонимный класс, то такой объект может остаться в памяти надолго и сборщик мусора может его не собрать... В общем, резюме следующее. События оформлять (или, по меньшей мере, уметь оформлять) стандартным образом. Против использования LINQ, на сколько я понял, противопоказаний нет никаких. Лямбдами и прочим стандартные обработчики не подменять.

По поводу рекомендаций:
В C# разрешается формировать какие угодно разновидности событий, но ради совместимости программных компонентов следует придерживаться рекомендаций, установленных Microsoft. Эти рекомендации сводятся к следующему требованию: у обработчиков событий должно быть два параметра. Первый — ссылка на объект, формирующий событие, второй — параметр типа EventArgs, содержащий любую дополнительную информацию о событии, которая требуется обработчику. Таким образом, .NET-совместимые обработчики событий должны иметь следующую общую форму:
void Обработчик(object отправитель, EventArgs данныеСобытия) {
    // код
}

отправитель — это параметр, передаваемый вызывающим кодом с помощью ключевого слова this. А параметр данныеСобытия типа EventArgs (или производного от него типа) содержит дополнительную информацию о событии и может быть проигнорирован, если он не нужен. Класс EventArgs не содержит поля, которые могут быть использованы для передачи дополнительных данных обработчику. Класс EventArgs служит в качестве базового класса, от которого получается производный класс, содержащий все необходимые поля. Также EventArgs имеется одно static поле Empty, которое представляет собой объект типа EventArgs без данных.
Пример кода (проверял на .NET 8):
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Инициализация
        var stock = new Stock();
        var stockWrapper = new StockWrapper(stock);
        
        // Вызываем основной код
        stock.Price = 100M;
        stock.Price = 200M;
        stock.Price = 300M;
        
        // Не даём закрыться консоли после выполнения
        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}

/// <summary>
/// Событие
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lastPrice">Прошлая стоимость</param>
/// <param name="newPrice">Новая стоимость</param>
class PriceChangedEventArgs(decimal lastPrice, decimal newPrice) : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Прошлая стоимость
    /// </summary>
    public decimal LastPrice { get; } = lastPrice;
    /// <summary>
    /// Новая стоимость
    /// </summary>
    public decimal NewPrice { get; } = newPrice;
}

/// <summary>
/// Обёртка над <see cref="Stock"/>
/// </summary>
class StockWrapper
{
    public StockWrapper(Stock stock)
    {
        stock.PriceChanged += Stock_PriceChanged!;
    }
   
    /// <summary>
    /// Обработчик события
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Объект отправитель</param>
    /// <param name="e">Данные события</param>
    private void Stock_PriceChanged(object sender, PriceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Выводим на консоль данные события
        Console.WriteLine($"OldPrice: {e.LastPrice} | NewPrice: {e.NewPrice}");
    }
}

class Stock
{
    private decimal _price;
    /// <summary>
    /// Текущая стоимость
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Price
    {
        set
        {
            // Если значение не изменилось, не меняем его и не вызываем событие
            if (_price == value)
                return;
            
            // Если изменилось, то меняем значение и создаём событие для всех подписчиков на него
            decimal lastPrice = _price;
            decimal newPrice = value;
            PriceChanged(this, new PriceChangedEventArgs(lastPrice, _price = newPrice));
        }
    }
    
    // Тип EventHandler определён так: public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object? sender, TEventArgs e);
    public event EventHandler<PriceChangedEventArgs> PriceChanged = delegate { };
}


Благодарю за ответ! Значит требование только одно - два аргумента определенного типа у обработчика, а все остальное можно оформлять как удобно, я правильно понял?
Класс EventArgs - базовый для всех событий, это я в курсе, но вот смысл его передачи в обработчик я не совсем понимаю. За счет данного наследования становится возможной передача в один и тот же обработчик разных производных классов, но вот для чего они вообще могут понадобиться самому обработчику я не понимаю. Не могли бы привести пример, когда такой класс необходим или полезен?

Приложил пример кода

Добавлю, что не могу сказать что пример кода является реальным и он полезен, но тут наглядно можно увидеть как это работает. Дальше думаю ограничивается всё только воображением.

Благодарю за пример! Потребуется немного времени, чтобы все осмыслить, но думаю этого будет достаточно.

Там на видео вроде нормальный чел, говорит хорошо, в темпе, но несёт пургу.

Как написал @CrazyElf, "Linq и лямбды" никакого прямого отношения к элементам управления Windows Forms не имеют. В примере они используются по своему назначению - для обработки перечислений (IEnumerable). В частности, с помощью этих функций автор получает из строчного массива массив объектов типа MenuItem.
(sender,args)=>CreateReport(name) - это такая лямбда, которая соответствует сигнатуре обработчика события Click, а именно имеет два аргумента соотвествующих типов. Студия покажет, что тип аргумента sender - object, а args - EventArgs. И никакой другой вариант не подойдёт. То есть sender никуда не девается. Просто эти аргументы в лямбде игнорируются. Кстати, сейчас это можно записать как (_, _) => CreateReport(name).
Зачем sender? Чтобы в обработчике события был доступ к объекту, который вызвал этот обработчик. Поскольку обработчик - это внешний по отношению к элементу управления метод, то передать в него информацию об этом элементе управления можно только таким способом. Нужна такая информация? Очевидно, нужна.
Лямбда с замыканием компилируется в специальный класс, который имеет поля для значений переменных замыкания, и метод - собственно саму лямбду, которая ссылается на эти поля. Поскольку лямбда находится в методе Select, который вызываетя для каждого элемента коллекции monthNames, т. е. 12 раз, то во время выполнения создаётся 12 вспомогательных объектов со значением переменной замыкания, и событие Click каждого элемента массива menuItems получает ссылку на метод лямбды своего индивидульного объекта. То есть с помощью Linq и лямбда-выражения он автоматизировал создание обработчиков. А вот когда он создал MenuItemSelected, то это действительно стал единственный обработчик на 12 команд меню. И обработчик берёт название месяца из аргумента sender.

// это примерно то, что он создал
class MenuItemSelected {
    string _name;
    public MenuItemSelected(string name) { _name = name;}
    public void Lambda(object sender, EventArgs args) => CreateReport(_name);
}
items[0].Click += new MenuItemSelected("январь").Lambda;
items[1].Click += new MenuItemSelected("февраль").Lambda;
// и т. д.

Правильным вариантом будет второй, а дополнительный метод можно убрать:
static void MenuItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show($"создаю отчёт за {(sender as MenuItem).Text}...");
...
var menuItems = monthNames.Select(name =>
    {
        var menuItem = new MenuItem(name);
        menuItem.Click += MenuItemSelected;
        return menuItem;
    }).ToArray();

// или то же самое, но с лямбдой
// здесь она просто порождает анонимный метод без сюрпризов

var menuItems = monthNames.Select(name =>
    {
        var menuItem = new MenuItem(name);
        menuItem.Click += (sender, _) => { MessageBox.Show($"создаю отчёт за {(sender as MenuItem).Text}..."); }
        return menuItem;
    }).ToArray();

Если для каждой команды меню нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, то класс Control, от которого унаследованы все элементы управления Windows Forms, прелагает свойство Tag, в которое можно записать ссылку на объект с дополнительной информаций.
static void MenuItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    var mi = sender as MenuItem;
    MessageBox.Show($"создаю отчёт за {mi.Text}...");
    var to = mi.Tag as ATargetType;
    to. ...
}


Искать что-то в Гугле - это такое... Начинать нужно с документации.
Про конвенцию. Конвенция с sender - это одна из парадигм ООП - инкапсуляция. См. п. 3.
С этим автором программировать вы научитесь, конечно, но понимать, что вы делаете, скорее всего, будете плохо. А так видосы норм.
Это видео (которое у вас первоисточник) после 7:03 слушать категорически нельзя. Про WPF тоже пурга.
Кстати, если вы захотите использовать команду меню с галочкой, то менять её состояние в обработчике Click без sender у вас никак не получится, и никакой лямбдой тут не извратишься.

P. S. Зачем нужен EventArgs? Вы посмотрите что-то посложнее команды меню, например DataGridView. Возьмём событие CellClick, которое в объекте производного от EventArgs класса сообщает обработчику, на какой именно ячейке случился Click.

Спасибо за ответ, но хоть убейте, не понимаю - что и где там 12 штук создается. И в 1, и во 2 примере создаются массивы MenuItem-ов, но это нормально. Всё остальное - это делегаты, т.е. ссылки. Их копировать можно сколько угодно, они всё равно все ведут в одно место. Да, из метода-обработчика мы не узнаем кто его вызвал, но тут это не нужно. А если бы было нужно, то ничто не мешает передать в обработчик сам объект MenuItem посредством той же лямбды.
Мне стиль кода этого преподавателя тоже не нравится, многое сейчас является недопустимым. Поэтому и задаю столько вопросов - как же правильно...

См. дополнение к ответу. Что такое в вашем понимании "стиль кода"? В общем понимании у автора курсов стиль написания кода вполне себе хороший.

Я больше про скобки, отступы, явное разделение блоков кода и т.п.
По поводу лямбд. По моей информации, лямбда-выражение может компилироваться в метод или в дерево выражений в зависимости от контекста. Если лямбда присваивается делегату или используется в методах, принимающих делегат, то лямбда будет скомпилирована в метод, а на каждой итерации будут создаваться лишь экземпляры делегатов, каждый из которых из-за замыкания будет иметь собственное значение переменной name. Дублирование методов, на сколько я знаю, невозможно - каждый существует в единственном экземпляре. Поправьте если ошибся

Делегат не хранит значения аргументов

Я просто опустил этот момент, ибо он и так понятен. Делегат да, не хранит. Он указывает на класс с анонимным методом, в который разворачивается лямбда-выражение, а переменные участвующие в замыкании становятся полями этого класса. Поэтому и существует такое явление как замыкание.
По поводу DataGridView и CellClick - запомнил, попробую с ними поэкспериментировать. Возможно, это поможет лучше разобраться в теме. Спасибо за помощь!

Лямбда с замыканием компилируется в специальный класс, который имеет поля для значений переменных замыкания, и статический метод - собственно саму лямбду, которая ссылается на эти поля: вроде же не статический? А то иначе как получить доступ к полям?

@VladD через ''this'')))) Было бы желание)) А вот по поводу того, что из лямбды получится не 1 а аж целых 12 классов, я считаю, перебор. У лямбды есть имя, и потому она должна быть ассоциирована с одним конкретным классом, иначе как сам компилятор в них ориентироваться будет. Итого должен получиться класс с одним методом и 12-ю разными полями. А вот статическими или нет - это вопрос. Мы же не создаем экземпляры лямбд при работе. Если бы это было возможно, тогда превратить метод в объект было бы проще простого с помощью лямбды. Так что скорее всего класс, поля и метод статические.

@JamesBond: Так не получится, статический метод не имеет доступа к this.

@VladD сам метод не имеет, но можно вызвать этот метод из другого передав ему объект данного класса с помощью this. Я не говорю что так нужно или что это возможный вариант устройства класса, на который указывает лямбда - это просто был рофл)

@JamesBond если вы с Владом общаетесь, так комментируйте его ответ. А вообще, выглядит так, что вы пытаетесь что-то пообсуждать ради обсуждения. На каждый ваш вопрос у вас есть собственный же ответ. Хорош Интернет засорять. Не знаешь - спросил - получил ответ - уточнил, если надо - всё.
